# Method Not Allowed.The method is not allowed for the requested URL. On Flask

Tags: flask, http-status-code-405

Used the following in cmd:

```
    set FLASK_APP=hello_app.py
    flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

code: 
'''

```
<input id="name-input" type="text"/>
<button id="name-button">Submit</button>
<p id="greeting"></p>

<script href="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#name-button').click(function(event){
        let message = {
            name: $('#name-input').val()
        }
        $.post('http://192.168.1.106:5000/hello', JSON.stringify(message), function(response){
            $('#greeting').text(response.greeting);
            console.log(response);
        });
    });
</script>
```

'''

```
    from flask import Flask
    from flask import jsonify
    from flask import request

    app = Flask(__name__)
    @app.route('/hello', methods=['POST'])
    def hello():
        message = request.get_json(force=True)
        name = message['name']
         response = {
            'greeting':'Hello,' + name + '!'
        }
        return jsonify(response)

   if '__name__' == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)'''
```

Got 405 error while running. Already tried adding 'GET' to the methods which led to Bad Request instead.
Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the methods to ['GET','POST']

```
@app.route("/home",methods=['GET','POST'])
```

THEN handle the post data by

```
if request.method=='POST':
    #handle post data here
else:
    #return a normal page
    return "home"
```

also change the last if '**name**' == '**main**': to this
`if __name__ == '__main__':`

EDIT:
add your jsonify code in the handle post data section

Comment: seems the server in not starting

Comment: This code should start the server. Place at the bottom of the file `if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)`

Comment: invalid syntax.

Comment: Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: NameError: name 'render_template' is not defined

Comment: Does the html and py file need to be in same folder?

Comment: the html file needs to be in a folder called templates. then you can use render_template to show the html file. use this code to import render_templates: `from flask import render_template`